# Selenium Webdriver : I am not able to switch to iframe

Tags: selenium, firebug, firepath

Here is the code that I have written.I have tried adding `thread.sleep()` but it still doesn't work also tried with chromedriver but same result

```
package com.thinksys.frames;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Iframes 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\Users\\thinksysuser\\Downloads\\geckodriver-v0.18.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe");

        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.irctc.co.in/eticketing/loginHome.jsf");

        WebElement e = driver.findElement(By.id("google_ads_iframe_/37179215/DFP_NGET_01_HomePage_RHS_ATF_479x266_ENG_0"));

        driver.switchTo().frame(e);

        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='image-11']/a/img")).click();
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. Add some implicit wait. 2. For switching the frame you can use the index of the frame or id of the frame. So no need to create webelement and just use the id inside driver.switchTo().frame(id_goes_here);

Comment: I have tried that. Still doesnt work

Comment: what you have tried. Can you tell me the id of the frame that you need to switch?

Comment: The id  is mentioned in the web element

Comment: can you try using index like `driver.switchTo().frame(0);` and let me know the outcome

Comment: yeah. I used index zero since there is only one frame on the site

Comment: Let me try 1 and 2 also just in case I missed some frames by chance

Comment: Still not working

Comment: can you clear what you want to do on that site, I open the same site and i'm not able to see any frame with the id `google_ads_iframe_/37179215/DFP_NGET_01_HomePage_RHS_ATF_479x266_ENG_0` even there is no element `.//*[@id='image-11']/a/img` on page

Comment: I want to click on the advertisement on the right named IRCTC attractions

Comment: It is a frame and .//*[@id='image-11']/a/img is its absolute xpath

Comment: have you seen the ad image on the browser opened by your script ?

Comment: @Akashdeep Singh, if you are seeing the ad image in the browser opened by script. then can you mentioned the error you getting.

Comment: Are you trying to click on Green binker?

Comment: You won't be able to see the advertisement in incognito mode. That is why it is unable to click. Further, script always open in private mode.

Comment: I am running it in normal mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might caused by the special characters in the `<ifram>` id. Using partial id will provide two matches, so I suggest you use two portions of the name attribute

```
WebElement frame = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[name*='google_ads_iframe'][name*='DFP_NGET_01_HomePage_RHS']"));
driver.switchTo().frame(frame);
```

> Edit

The images rotates, each on is visible for a few seconds only. To click on a specific image you need to wait for it to be visible. You can use explicit wait for it

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60, 50);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocatedBy.xpath(".//*[@id='image-11']/a/img"))).click();
```

This will pole the DOM every 100 milliseconds until the image is visible or the time is up (60 seconds).

Comment: I did try the AND operation but it still doesnt work.....Is there any chance that it is a browser or system problem because I did face a system problem last time

Comment: @AkashdeepSingh `cssSelector` doesn't have `AND`, and in `xpath` its with lowercase `and`. Please try exactly the code I provided.

Comment: I was talking about xpath only, let me try your code

Comment: I was really positive about this one but still not working

Comment: @AkashdeepSingh What didn't work? the switch or the clicking after that? and what exactly happened? *not working* is not really informative.

Comment: Sorry about that, I am not able to execute the click part

Comment: which MP means that my code cannot switch to the frame

Comment: Thanks, I should have taken that into account

Comment: if we can calculate the amount of time after which that picture repeats then we can use Thread.sleep too, Correct?

Comment: @AkashdeepSingh Theoretically yes, but it will work only if the images are always loaded in the same order and the number of images never changes. If the target image is visible in different intervals it won't be possible, and you will have to update the code every time a image is removed or added.

Comment: True that, Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

There is variations on browsers to display ads. I have opened in Firefox and not able to see the ad while its displaying in chrome. and the scenario while i do open the Chrome or Firefox browser using script there is no ad section.

based on this scenario you can check that weather frame is available or not if available then switch into it and wait till the image you gonna click get visible then click on it

You can try this way :

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 120);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[starts-with(@id,'google_ads_iframe')][@title='3rd party ad content']"))));

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='image-11']/a/img")))).click();
```

or

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 120);
List <WebElement> adFrame = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//iframe[starts-with(@id,'google_ads_iframe')][@title='3rd party ad content']"))
   if(adFrame.size()>0)
    {
        driver.switchTo().frame(adFrame.get(0));
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='image-11']/a/img")))).click();
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Sorry there is no ads");
    }
```